# Полнотекстовый поиск по нескольким столбцам

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть условная таблица `normalized_documents`:

```
       Column       |    Type    | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
--------------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer    |           | not null | nextval('indexing_results_id_seq'::regclass)
 document_id        | integer    |           |          |
 normalized_title   | tsvector   |           | not null |
 normalized_content | tsvector   |           | not null |
```

С помощью функции `to_tsquery()` будет производиться полнотекстовый поиск по двум столбцам: `normalized_title` и `normalized_content` (кол-во колонок в запросе будет всегда равно двум и меняться не будет). Есть 3 вопроса:

1. Как эффективнее сформировать индекс [GIN](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/textsearch-indexes)? Создать 2 индекса по 2 колонкам или же один составной?
2. Возможно ли задать вес столбцам при поиске? Например, чтобы колонка `normalized_title` имела вес 2, а вес результатов из `normalized_content` был бы равен 1.
3. Как эффективнее всего выполнять полнотекстовый поиск по 2 столбцам? Есть ли наиболее оптимальное (ну или правильное) решение? Пример запроса ниже.

Вот примерный запрос, который я планирую использовать для поиска:

```
-- ищем упоминания слов "договор" или "участник" в двух столбцах
SELECT document_id FROM normalized_documents WHERE normalized_title || normalized_content @@ to_tsquery('russian', 'договор | участник');
```

Буду очень признателен любой информации по теме.